# Как правильно подписаться к event'у, который вызывается в другом потоке?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня работает UDP Socket, который читает информацию с broadcast сервера. Мне нужно, чтобы когда у меня формировалось сообщение от сервера срабатывал event и метод обработки этого event'a начал работать в основном потоке. Вот так у меня это сделано. Поток читает всё что посылает сервер, но когда дело доходит до Invoke, ничего не происходит

Сам класс:

```
public class UdpLocation
{
    public event UdpLocationEventHandler MessageReceived;

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(StartListen)
        { IsBackground = true };

        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        StartListen();
    }

        private void StartListen()
        {

            if (IPAddress == string.Empty || Port == 0)
                throw new Exception("IPAddress or Port is non initilizated");

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(IPAddress), Port));

            EndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while (true)
            {
                do
                {
                    client.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteIP);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data));

                } while (client.Available > 0);

                MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new UdpLocationEventArgs()
                {
                    Latitude = builder.ToString(),
                    Longitude = builder.ToString()
                });

                builder.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Его использование:

```
class Proga
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UdpLocation location = new UdpLocation() { IPAddress = "192.168.0.2", Port = 8080 };
        location.Start();

        location.MessageReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.Latitude} {e.Longitude}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я наконец-таки понял что нужно подписываться на event раньше, чем запустится поток чтения сервера. Ещё я отказался от класса UdpLocationEventArgs и сделал так:

```
        public string Longitude
        {
            get
            {
                return _long;
            }

            set
            {
                _long = value;
                MessageReceived.Invoke(this, new UdpLocationEventArgs() { Longitude = value });
            }
        }

        public string Latitude
        {
            get
            {
                return _lat;
            }

            set
            {
                _lat = value;
                MessageReceived.Invoke(this, new UdpLocationEventArgs() { Latitude = value });
            }
        }
```

Ещё немного видоизменил цикл обработки:

```
        private void StartListen()
        {
            // ...
            while (true)
            {
                do
                {
                    client.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteIP);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data));

                } while (client.Available > 0);

                Latitude = builder.ToString();
                Longitude = builder.ToString();

                builder.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Само использование выглядит так:

```
class Proga
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UdpLocation location = new UdpLocation() { IPAddress = "192.168.0.2", Port = 8080 };
        location.MessageReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.Latitude} {e.Longitude}");
        location.Start();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```